# What is tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator attribute in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

ConstraintLayout is new in android so anybody know what is `tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="0"` and what purpose does it serve to the attributes. Below is my code.

```
<Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="144dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="39dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="0"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button"
        tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This attribute is used only for the editor. `tools:` attributes are stripped from the code and are only for development purposes.

I'm not sure what `layout_constraintBaseline_creator`is about but my gut says that the layout editor ***ONLY*** generates it when a constraint is created. `ConstraintLayout` is not yet documented.

Comment: The "creator" attribute is used to know who created the constraint (you, auto inference, auto connect, etc.). It allows the designer to "remember" what you did and act accordingly to avoid surprises (for instance when you click auto inference, the editor won't destroy the constraints you created).

Comment: It would be great to document this somewhere.

Comment: @RomainGuy it would be great to be able to stop generating these, as well as the layout_edit_absoluteX, Y etc for people that want to work with the xml directly and not with the visual editor